# Very peculiar network issue on Debian 9 - Realtek network cards

Tags: debian, networking, networkmanager, ethernet, realtek

**My OS**: OS in question, and my primary OS: **Debian 9.1** (fresh install) with [i3 window manager](http://www.i3wm.org) (no DE). Other OSes (dual booted): Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows 10.

**Kernel**: `4.9.0-3-amd64`

**Network cards info**: **Realtek 8101** ethernet controller which works out-of-the-box (verified many times in Debian 9, Ubuntu, ...) and a **Realtek 8723be** Wireless network adapter which needs [additional tweaking](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645220/unable-to-connect-wifi-ubuntu-14-04-lts-hp-pavilion-network-driver-rtl8723be/729660#729660) (Installation of a driver patch - due to a fault in the default drivers - tried by myself, it worked fine.).

I installed **`network-manager-gnome`** to manage my networks (although ethernet is *unmanaged* by it since eno1 (my ethernet) appears in `/etc/networks/interfaces`)

**Problem:** Network (**neither** ethernet nor WiFi) doesn't work on fresh reboot. By this I mean that - if I directly boot into Debian and try accessing the internet, it doesn't work. But, if I first boot into say, my Ubuntu, login to the internet there (see *Additional info 1* below) and come back to Debian, it works! I have tried this a lot of times and the pattern is always that.

**Additional info 1**: I am accessing internet from a university campus, so there's a network login page that I must first visit and login. I can't open this login page upon a fresh restart, but if I already login and come to Debian, I can! I find this very strange.

**EDIT**: There's **no** proxy server involved. Just a login page.

**Additional info 2**: There's a [known kernel-panic bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=866376) associated with my particular Wireless network adapter, `network-manager-gnome` and Debian. I experienced it as follows: If I don't install that said driver patch for my Wireless adapter, I experience kernel-panic during bootup (sometimes multiple times) and if I *do* install it, there's no kernel-panic.

To confirm this is indeed the reason for kernel-panic, I checked the `syslog` at `/var/log/syslog` and observed something on the lines of `wlo1...` just prior to the kernel-panic entry.

And please note, with that driver patch I can use my Wireless adapter perfectly fine (provided I login to internet in my Ubuntu for a and come back!).

**My question**: Why does my network show such a strange pattern, how do I correct it? Any leads would be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Guess: Both Realtek cards need either to download firmware, or need hardware initialization that the Ubuntu kernel + firmware packages provide, while the Debian kernel doesn't and/or has the wrong or no firmware images. Compare `dmesg` output after boot of both distros to verify this guess.

Comment: Thanks for the response @dirkt. I'll return back in a while.

Answer (score -1):

At the bottom of:

https://wiki.debian.org/DualBoot/Windows

It says to add NETDOWN="no" to /etc/default/halt so that linux doesnt 'shutdown' with out the win drivers permission.

Comment: How will that fix the problem described?